# Storm Topology Submitted Remotely not running

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

We created a storm topology and tested in local mode and everything works great. We then did a build and submitted to nimbus and one supervisor with 4 slots. The topology appears on the storm UI and is shown as active, with 4 slots used on the cluster. But when the topology is clicked, there are no spouts, no bolts, no statistics information. Nothing is written to our Redis database either. So we are wondering if there is something we are not doing.

Storm version: 2.0.0 
OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon

Comment: Most likely your topology is failing to start for some reason. Take a look at the logs directory in Storm. Most likely Storm will log what is wrong there. You most likely want to look in `logs/workers-artifacts/`

Comment: Thanks Stig. The bolts were not appearing because the workers were not connected. Storm couldn't access the supervisor which was another host because it couldn't resolve the ip from the of the machine. So we edited both the host files of nimbus node and the supervisor node. Next it was a ```ClassNotFoundException``` for Jedis. We packaged the jar with all its dependencies and deployed it and it ran just fine.

Comment: We do have another issue though. When two supervisors are used, both can't communicate even though we have added the IP address of each node to the host files of the other node? How could we resolve that?

Comment: I'm not sure. You will need to ensure that you can access the `supervisor.slots.ports` on each supervisor. So if e.g. supervisor 2 has port 6700, you should ensure that you can access `supervisor2:6700` from supervisor 1.